# Adding date filter In dashboard Metabase

Tags: google-analytics, metabase

I have Native query from My Google Analytics like this:

```
{
  "ids": "ga:MY_GA_IDs",
  "start-date": "2019-05-01",
  "end-date": "2019-05-31",
  "metrics": "ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:transactionsPerSession,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue",
  "dimensions": "ga:city",
  "sort": "ga:city",
  "filters": "ga:country=~(?i)indonesia",
  "include-empty-rows": false,
  "max-results": 10000
}
```

I try adding date filter for my dashboard using tag {{date_variable}} But it's not working. How can I adding dynamic date filter to my Dashboard?

Comment: There is an option metabase to create variables (left-hand side "X") before that you need to put {{date_variable}} in your sql native query. It will automatically show the variable creation when you click on the icon for variable creation. Put the default value in the for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

For Metabase, on the dashboard page top right if you choose "Edit dashboard" like this -->:
[image]

Then choose "add filter" and link the filter to your {{example}} area in each table, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be better off the query builder  when working with Analytics in metabase. The integration is not fully functional (check [this](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/7892) and [this](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/9476) issues for instance).

Check this post on metabase forum as a guidance (some other user had a very similar problem): 
https://discourse.metabase.com/t/variables-in-google-analytics-native-query/4436